# Angularjs strap tab inside tab

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-strap

I am trying to implement tab inside tab view in AngularJS by using  angularstrap 2.1.0.

There are n main tab like "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3", ..."Tabn" and each tab can have m subtabs like "Subtab1", "Subtab2", ..."Subtabm".

HTML

```
    <div ng-controller="myController">

      <div bs-active-pane="activeTab" bs-tabs="true">

      <div ng-repeat="tab in tabs" data-title="{{ tab.title }}" bs-pane="true">

         <div>Hello, tab : {{tab.title}}</div>

      <div bs-active-pane="tab.activeSubTab" bs-tabs="true">

        <div ng-repeat="subTab in tab.subtabs" data-title="{{ subTab.title }}" bs-pane="true">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['mgcrea.ngStrap']);

app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function(scope) {
  scope.tabs = [{
     title: 'Home',
   }, {
     title: 'Profile',
   }, {
     title: 'About',
 }];
 scope.activeTab = 0;

for (var index in scope.tabs) {
    var subtabs = [{
      title: 'sub1',
    }, {
      title: 'sub2',
    }, {
      title: 'sub3',
    }];
    scope.tabs[index].subtabs = subtabs;
    scope.tabs[index].activeSubTab = 0;
}

}]);
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Raj_13290/jg9ehtj7/)

I tried to implement but it is giving error

> Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: $pane in $panes, Duplicate key: object:01E

Does angularstrap tab support this kind of view? If not how should I implement this?

Comment: Looks like this was a known issue with angular-strap before v2.1.4 (https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/pull/1280).  Looks like you'll need to upgrade to at least 2.1.4 and add 'track by $index' to your ng-repeat.

Comment: @jbrown thanks, it worked by changing version of angularstrap. But I am working on legacy system, changing version will be difficult :(